# Jump/Reload to same page from Ajax success function on razor view in MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, razor

Here is my Ajax call, I am calling an API that updates the database and I want page to be reloaded on success function.

```
 $("#Pendingbookings").on("click", ".AcceptBooking", function () {
                    var button = $(this);
                    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to accept this booking?", function (result) {
                        if (result) {
                            var Booking = { BookingID: button.attr("data-BookingId") }
                            var url_redirect = '@Url.Action("GetBookingsByStatus", "Booking")';
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "/api/AcceptBooking/AcceptBooking",
                                method: "PUT",
                                data: Booking,
                                dataType: 'json',
                                success: function (response) {
                                    window.location.href = url_redirect;
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Ajax calls works fine, data is updated in database but it never reloads the page or call the action method on success call

API

```
[HttpPut]
        public IHttpActionResult AcceptBooking(Booking BookingID)
        {
            //Write the function to update booking and accept it.
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            int bookingID = BookingID.BookingID;

            var bookingInDB = _context.Booking.SingleOrDefault(c => c.BookingID == bookingID);

            if (bookingInDB == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                bookingInDB.BookingAccepted = true;
            }

            _context.Entry(bookingInDB).State = EntityState.Modified;

            _context.SaveChanges();

            return Ok();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try by removing the dataType from the ajax call.

```
 $.ajax({
         url: "/api/AcceptBooking/AcceptBooking",
         method: "PUT",
         data: Booking,                    
         success: function (response) {
         window.location.href = url_redirect;
         }
        });
```